# How does the dimension value of the musgrave texture affect the output?

Tags: shader-nodes

The official blender documentation for the musgrave texture states:
Dimension:
The difference between the magnitude of each two consecutive octaves. Larger values corresponds to smaller magnitudes for higher octaves.

But how is the magnitude calculated using the dimension input? One reasonable guess would be 1/dimension but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: Replacing my original answer because of an off-by-one error.

It turns out that the Musgrave texture mapping includes a hidden input.  If you enumerate the inputs you get:

```
0 Vector
1 W
2 Scale
3 Detail
4 Dimension
5 Lacunarity
6 Offset
7 Gain
```

So my original assumptions were off. Let's *carefully* track down the "dimension" input.

1. In `properties_texture.py` it is defined, not as "dimension, but as [`dimension_max`](https://github.com/dfelinto/blender/blob/c4ef90f5a0b1d05b16187eb6e32323defe6461c0/release/scripts/startup/bl_ui/properties_texture.py#L551)
2. In `rna_texture.c` it is given the internal RNA [`mg_H`](https://github.com/dfelinto/blender/blob/c4ef90f5a0b1d05b16187eb6e32323defe6461c0/release/scripts/startup/bl_ui/properties_texture.py#L551)
3. In `texture_procedural.c` in various places it is used as the 4th argument to the indirect function `mgravefunc`, for example in [this call](https://github.com/dfelinto/blender/blob/c4ef90f5a0b1d05b16187eb6e32323defe6461c0/source/blender/render/intern/texture_procedural.c#L549).
4. `mgravefunc` depends on the Musgrave type.  In the previous step it might be `BLI_noise_mg_multi_fractal` or `BLI_noise_mg_fbm`.
5. The various noise functions are defined in [blender/source/blender/blenlib/intern/noise.c](https://github.com/dfelinto/blender/blob/c4ef90f5a0b1d05b16187eb6e32323defe6461c0/source/blender/blenlib/intern/noise.c)  The 4th argument is always called `H`

Oddly enough this *does* bring us to the [code](https://github.com/dfelinto/blender/blob/c4ef90f5a0b1d05b16187eb6e32323defe6461c0/source/blender/blenlib/intern/noise.c#L1342) I cited in the incorrect version of the answer, only we need to look at the variable `H`:

```
  float value = 0.0, pwr = 1.0, pwHL = powf(lacunarity, -H);
```

It is used as an exponent of lacunarity.

Comment: I don't think that this code snippit actually covers the dimension value. It rather looks like the code for generating the perlin noise iterartivelyusing octaves, which however refers to the detail value in the musgrave node not the dimension.

Comment: After reading the code, I couldn't find where the dimension value turns into the octaves variable. The only thing I found is: "//``octaves''  is the number of frequencies in the fBm". WHich considering the nature of perlin noise (blender for some reason calls it musgrave) would be exactly what the detail input would be.

Comment: I followed the code, but no matter how I look at it I can't see how the octaves variables could correspond to a input parameter other than 'detail'.

Comment: @tempdevnova thanks for keeping me honest.  Right code fragment wrong variable. I think the answer is right now.

Comment: Yes, H seems to be the dimension value, great! So as I understand the code, it does the following with the musgrave dimension value: First it uses the powf function to return a value to a variable called pwHL. The pwHL then multiplies the pwr variable every loop iteration, which then drives the values of the individual noise layers in line 1344. The only question now is where the powf function is specified.

Comment: powf is a standard C function from the math library.  To quote from a manual "The pow(), powf(), and powl() functions compute x raised to the power of y."

Comment: Now everything makes sense, thanks! Just curious since I'm not acquainted with the standart C function library but what is the difference between pow(), powf(), and powl()?

Comment: The return value's size.  pow returns a double precision float, powf returns a 'float' which can default to various sizes and powl returns a quad precision (long double) float. [pow](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/pow/?kw=powl) has details